# Что означает инструкция: self.__set_x(x)?

Tags: python, классы, init

Мне не понятен смысл инструкции self.__set_x(x). По всем канонам это должна быть операция присваивания т.е. self.__set_x = x. Вот полный код и он работает:

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__set_x(x)               

    def __get_x(self):
        print("Get X")
        return self.__x
    
    def __set_x(self, x):
        self.__x = x
        print("Set X")

    x = property(__get_x, __set_x)
```

Comment: Это называется сеттер и геттер. Почитайте про них.

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю что такое сеттер и геттер. Но я нигде (!) не нашел их сочетание с - х(х) - maestro :)

Comment: А как же по вашему должны быть описаны сеттеры и геттеры в классе? Они именно в виде специальных методов и описываются

Comment: Есть три способа: 1. Обычный 2. Через декоратор 3. Через функцию-декоратор - это мой случай. В лит. описана инициализация как self.__x = x . А у меня стоит  self.__set_x(x). Мне не понятно и я не могу найти ответа. Помоги если можешь...

Comment: Айдар, вопрос, скорее, откуда такой код взялся, и зачем он такой? Остальное - в ответе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте попробую описать на примере. Ниже ваш код и пара строк вызова вашего класса `Data`

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__set_x(x)               

    def __get_x(self):
        print("Get X")
        return self.__x
    
    def __set_x(self, x):
        self.__x = x
        print("Set X")

    x = property(__get_x, __set_x)
    
myx = Data( 1 )    
print( myx.x )
```

Если запустить эту программу, то мы увидим такой результат

```
Set X
Get X
1
```

`self.__set_x(x)` в конструкторе класса вызывает собственную функцию установки переменной икс `x`

Вместо этого, наверное, можно было написать прямо в конструкторе

`self.__set_x = x`

Но нет. При попытке такого присваивания получаем ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    print( myx.x )
  File "main.py", line 8, in __get_x
    return self.__x
AttributeError: 'Data' object has no attribute '_Data__x'
```

Потому что `__set_x` это не переменная и в неё ничего нельзя присваивать. `__set_x` - это функция или метод, а значит мы должны передать в неё значение, вызывав эту функцию и открыть круглые скобки, т.е. вот так `self.__set_x( x )`

Comment: Как же я не догадался, что это вызов собственной(!) функции... и только ради того, чтобы запустить print('Set X').  Питон :)

Comment: кроме ```print('Set X')``` она же ещё и саму переменную устанавливает ```__x = x``` :)

Comment: Айдар, к "как не догадался?" - надо было либо на бумажке посмотреть, как работает, либо в отладчике. И увидели бы.

Answer (score 3):

Разницы большой нет. `self.__set_x(x)` вызывает как раз "литературный" `self.__x = x` из метода класса. Если в отладчике по шагам идти, то видно, как ведёт себя класс.

Например, код ниже с обращением к классу:

```
a = Data(5)
```

даст на выходе: "Set X". Идя в отладчике по шагам, мы модем видеть, что после обращения к классу в строке выше далее мы попадаем в `__init__(self, x)`, который сразу вызывает метод класса `__set_x(self, x)`, где и срабатывает `self.__x = x`.

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если сильно понравилось:-)

Answer (score 3):

Ну просто при таком способе описания геттера и сеттера у вас есть в явном виде метод `__set_x`, так почему его нельзя вызвать при инициализации?

При более традиционном методе описания геттера и сеттера они получаются скрытыми, в явном виде методы геттера и сеттера не видимы как отдельные методы, поэтому их и не используют как методы.

В целом, конечно, питон довольно гибок и многое в нём можно делать разными способами. И тут мы видим как-раз такой пример. Но на мой взгляд геттеры и сеттеры как отдельные методы особого смысла не имеют и такой способ их описания лучше не использовать.